# How to get certain element in response from Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The code in my php file has many html elements that I am retrieving in AJAX response. Currently it returns all html elements in my drop area. How  I can  read just one element i.e. img as follows:

Php code:

```
<img src="<?php echo $target_file; ?>">
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $target_file?>" >
<img src= "<?php echo $target_file?>" alt="Image not found" style="width:150px">
</a>
<p align = "center"><b> EXIF INFORMATION </b></p>
```

Js file:

```
function uploadFormData(formData) 
{
  $.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType:false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
      $('#drop-area').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You can have multiple variables for each elements, and `return` the content of the required variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it will be better to return a json with the information you want to print in html format and compose the html in the javascript ajax success function, but you can work with the html dom in this way:

```
// Assuming you are using jQuery as $.ajax exists
var $data = $(data); // create a jquery element to search in dom
var $img = $(data.find("img:eq(1)")); // Get a reference to the img element at pos 1
... // work with element in normal jquery way
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your ajax success as below. It's a little overwork but you will get the desired result.

```
success: function(data){
     $('#drop-area').html(data);

    // will remove all the elements after the first image element
    $('#drop-area').find('>img:nth-child(1)').nextAll().remove();

    // need to read the first image element then can use below code
    var $firstImgObj = $('#drop-area').find('>img:nth-child(1)');
}
```